# Identify why vertical-middle/text-align:center doesn't center content?

Tags: html, css

I've tried solutions I found online and on this site (adding text-align:center, vertical-align:middle; to a table data row, and for some reason, it doesn't not work out for me, the way I want it to.)

I am currently taking an online course where I'm learning how to create html responsive emails, and I'm wanting to understand the approach better of alignment of content, specifically vertically. In the example below, what I'm thinking is to either take control over the table class "content" and the TD within it, that holds the text I'm wanting to vertically align. In the code, as you can see, I added the inline style with !important hoping it would take control of it.

What approach is best, when wanting to align content this way? The screenshot below shows what I'm wanting achieve. I wonder what I am doing wrong. **Edit:** I've only been able to add vertical-align: bottom to the first table that has class "column" and it sucesffully sent all that content to the bottom, but I'm not sure why vertical-align: middle doesn't work :(

[Screenshot what I'm wanting to achieve, with as sketch of structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwZ1m.png)

```html
<body style="Margin:0; padding:0; min-width: 100%; background-color: #dde0e1;">

  <center style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed; background-color: #dde0e1; padding-bottom: 20px;">

    <div style="max-width: 600px; background-color: #FAFDFE; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);">

      <!--mastertable_start-->
      <table align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; color: #565656; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica!important; background-color: #FAFDFE; Margin:0; padding: 0; width:100%; max-width: 600px;" role="presentation">

        <!--topheader_2columns_start-->
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:0; background-color: blue;">
            <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
              <tr>
                <td class="two-columns" style="padding:0; font-size:0; text-align: center;">

                  <table class="column" style="border-spacing:0; vertical-align: top; width:100%; max-width: 300px; display:inline-block;" role="presentation">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table class="content" style="border-spacing:0; text-align: left;" role="presentation">

                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rx31TX7/html-email.png" width="200" style="max-width: 200px;" border="0">
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr style="padding:0px;">
                            <td>
                              <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum this is some text</p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <table class="column" style="border-spacing:0; vertical-align: top; width:100%; max-width: 300px; display:inline-block;" role="presentation">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table class="content" style="border-spacing:0; text-align: left;" role="presentation">

                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nQn29Sg/woman-teal.jpg" width="300" border="0" style="max-width: 300px;">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

          </td>

        </tr>
        <!--topheader_end-->

      </table>
      <!--mastertable_end-->
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

**Thank you**

Comment: You've missed the outer table for your snippet.

Comment: Also, using tables isn't the best way of aligning things. Although I do understand that some email clients do not work to well with "modern" html.

Comment: Hi thanks @LeeTaylor for bringing that to my attention, sorry. I will post the table + tr code below. Yes, the course focuses on the tables in the html email as well as ghost tables for other applications that won't render some aspects of the email.

'<table align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; color: #565656; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica!important; background-color: #FAFDFE; Margin:0; padding: 0; width:100%; max-width: 600px;" role="presentation">
**CODE ABOVE GOES HERE**</table>'

Comment: No, please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: that's definitely too much table-nesting...

Comment: @LeeTaylor sorry , just now found the edit button! I updated the original snippet above to include the table and body. It includes those codes now.

Comment: No problem. I'll tidy it up for you